# Using WPF .NET APIs in a Windows 8.1 Universal application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, win-universal-app

As I am really really new to Universal Apps and I am coming from previous experience with WPF and Silverlight I was wondering if there is an approach I could use to take advantage of the .NET 4.5 APIs in an project created as Universal App. I know this might be a stupid question but as the idea of Universal Apps is to be "universal" it bright this thought to my head "Could I create a 'class library' for WPF and use it in an Universal App".

I have been researching this on the web but with no success so decided to test my luck here. Also if anyone could point me to some good resources in getting started with Universal app (for WPF/Silverlight .NET developers) it would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using Portable Class Libraries. It will give you the option to select which platforms to target. Keep in mind that the API surface available to Universal Apps are somewhat of a subset of the API surface available to WPF. This is somewhat analogous to how Silverlight was a subset of WPF in the beginning and then branched out somewhat over later versions.

Comment: That was what I was thinking also. Unfortunately it looks like there are quite a lot of missing APIs which makes portable libraries very limited :( still.

The one thing I was looking forward to use was the Process class from the System.Diagnostics namespace in System.dll. Do you know if there is a possible 'hack' of importing this assembly into a Universal app? Maybe something along the side of DllImport.